# Unit Test not passed, since not seen any return from api controller

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, moq, xunit

I have an API as below:

```
 private readonly IMyService _myService;
    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    //GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]

    public MyOutput<MyEntity> Get(string f, string o)
    {
        var fItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(f);
        var oItems = GetDictionaryFromStr(o ?? "");

        var myInput = new MyInput<MyEntity>()
        {
            PredicateDictionary = fItems,
            OrderByDictionary = oItems
        };

        var result = _myService.Search(myInput);

        return result;
    }
```

It works well. Now, I want to write a unit test for my API, using **Moq** and **Xunit**;. I want to set the expected values of result, then mock my DIs and call the controller, What I expect is that the return value of controller and my results be equal. but I don't know why result in `var result = api.Get(f, o);` **is null** after returns from controller. Is there anything wrong whit my test?

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_ReturnResult_When_CallingMyApi()
    {
        //Arrange
        var f = "{'Currency':'UR'}";
        var o = "+Amount";

        var fItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(f);
        var oItems = GetDictionaryFromStr(o ?? "");


        var baseServiceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();
        baseServiceMock 
            .Setup(x => x.Serach(It.Is<MyInput<MyEntity>>
                (i => i.PredicateDictionary== fItems
                 && i.OrderByDictionary == oItems
                 && i.Paging == pagingItems
                )))
            .Returns(new MyOutput<MyEntity>()
            {
                OrderByDictionary = oItems,
                PredicateDictionary = fItems
            });

        var api = new MyController(baseServiceMock.Object);



        //Act
        var result = api.Get(f, o);


        ////Assert
        Assert.Equal(result.PredicateDictionary, fItems);
        Assert.Equal(result.OrderByDictionary, oItems);
    }
```

**Update:**
Also I changed the `baseServiceMock`, with and without the `It.Is`. In case of `It.Is` I added

```
            baseServiceMock
            .Setup(x => x.Search(It.Is<MuInput<MyEntity>>
                (i => i.PredicateDictionary.Keys == fItems.Keys
                && i.PredicateDictionary.Values == fItems.Values
                && i.OrderByDictionary.Keys == oItems.Keys
                && i.OrderByDictionary.Values == oItems.Values
                && i.Paging == pagingItems
               )))
            .Returns.....
```

Comment: The issue lies with trying to get equality using the `It.IS<>` and collections. while troubleshooting you could use `It.IsAny<MuInput<MyEntity>>`. Also you can try using `CollectionAssert`

Comment: But I don't want to  skip validation. IsAny will skip, doesn't? I exactly want to tell to  Setup() that return MyOutput(...) for exactly these input parameters.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I was saying to use `IsAny` while debugging the problem. That is just so you can check that a result is actually being returned. Once that is confirmed then you can change it back to look at the other possibility that your asserts are not comparing the collections properly. With your current filter are you getting past the `Act` to your `Asserts`?

Comment: After Mocking the dependency to the controller, the api is null, so, result is null o, and the assert is not passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was comparing two objects in `SetUp()`. So I Edited the code as below:

```
 .Setup(x => x.Find(It.Is<MuInput<MyEntity>>
                (i => i.PredicateDictionary.First().Key == "Currency"
                && i.PredicateDictionary.First().Value == "CU_UR"
                && i.OrderByDictionary.First().Key == "Amount"
                 && i.OrderByDictionary.First().Value == "Asc")))
```

Comment: So you are saying that this works? If it does, glad you were able to find a solution to your problem. Happy coding.